# Bound and norm of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Prove that operator defined as 
$T(x_1, x_2, . . .) := (x_3, x_2, x_1, x_6, x_5, x_4, x_9, x_8, x_7, . . .)$
is a bounded linear operator on complex space $l^2$.

$ ||(x_1,x_2,x_3,..)|| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^2}$?

Can someone please help with finding its bound and norm?

Comment: When someone is telling you on $l^2$ without specifing the norm, then it is always the usual norm you wrote yourself. The operator has norm one, as it only permutes the entries (when taking the norm, i.e. taking the series, nothing changes).

Comment: Now that you know what norm you're working with, try calculating it for yourself.

Comment: $|| T(x_1,x_2,...)|| = ||(x_3,x_2,x_1,...)|| = \sqrt{\sum_i |x_i|^2} = ||x||$ is it true?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For all $x = (x_i)_i \in \ell^2$, $||x||_2 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^2 < \infty$, so $(x_i)_i$ is absolutely summable, and interchanging the order of terms inside the sum is OK.

> $$||(\bbox[5pt, border:1pt solid black]{x_3,x_2,x_1}, x_6,x_5,x_4,\dots)||  = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^2} = ||(\bbox[5pt, border:1pt solid black]{x_1,x_2,x_3},x_4,x_5,x_6,..)||$$ Therefore, $||Tx|| = ||x||$ for all $x \in \ell^2$, and $||T|| = 1$.